# Did Chronowerx appear in episode 11:59?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chronowerx_Industries):

> In the episode "11:59", a browser called "Browser Hound" by Chronowerx is seen briefly on-screen.

However, I can't see this browser or any trace of Chronowerx in this episode.

It's also not mentioned in [the episode summary](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/11:59_(episode)).

Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's hard to prove a negative, I strongly suspect that this is a case of [citogenisis](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/citogenesis.png). The earliest incidence of this 'fact' seems to be an [anonymous edit](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chronowerx_Industries?diff=746845&oldid=723115) (without confirmation) on Memory Alpha. Other websites have then quoted this fact (also without confirmation) as true.

So what do we see in the episode? Well, there are two computers seen. A laptop in a long shot with a blank screen.

[image]

And a laptop (possibly the same one) with a graphics package on it.

[image]

Neither appear to have any viewable text or discernible [Chronowerx logo](https://res.cloudinary.com/startrekdesignproject-com/image/upload/v1552523319/VOY3x08_Future_sEnd_ChronowerxIndustries_1.jpg).

Comment: I'd bet whoever did that did it to make us do exactly what we're doing now.

Comment: @nmit026 - It's possible. Either that or they've seen a much closer shot of that computer screen.

Comment: I tried to find a resolution high enough to see the computer desktop icons. Alas, it doesn't seem to be possible. I thought this was interesting because Chronowerx may still have existed as a normal Microsoft-type company in the Star Trek universe even if Starling hadn't found the timeship. (He's sort of a techno-hippy, a cross between Steve Jobs and Larry Ellison, the latter of which also loves being in the mountains. He may have planned to found and build Chronowerx anyway.)

Comment: @nmit026 - That's a screengrab from the highest resolution copy I can find. 1080p with enhancements. Suffice to say that the larger version (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVDDV.jpg) is larger, but no clearer